# Enable only mouse event over a jbutton - Disable keyboard event for jbutton

Tags: java, class, netbeans, jbutton, netbeans-7

I have a problem.
I created a game. When I open it I must press ENTER to start the game (just enter).
Now I upgraded the game with one button named "EXIT GAME". I don't know why my enter key doesn't work anymore because of this button. If i remove it then Ican press enter again and play the game.

I must set only click pressed event to that button or something like this? Please help me.

```
public class LeftPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton ExitGame;

    public LeftPanel(Tetris tetris) {
        this.tetris = tetris;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 480));
        setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(17f, 0.87f, 0.52f));
        add(new JButton("Exit Game"));
        {
            ExitGame.addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think its a typo `add(new new..` and it should be something `add(ExitGame)` make sure that you initialized it otherwise it will throw NPE.

Comment: `ExitGame.addActionListener(this);` Did you get a `NullPointerException` here?

Comment: @johnchen902 I didn't get a NullPointerException. How to do this?

Comment: @StanleyTips Just as MadProgrammer's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1 - The `JButton` is the only focusable component within your UI.  Therefore, when you start you program, it gains default focucs.  While it has default focus.  It will consume the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key strokes.

Problem 2 - `JPanel` is not focusable, meaning it can never receive key board focus.  From your description, I would assume you are using a `KeyListener`, which leads to

Problem 3 - Using `KeyListener`...`KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component it is registered to is focusable and has focus.  You can over come this by using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

...Solutions...

- Use `JLabel` instead of `JButton`.  This will require you to register a `MouseListener` to the label in order to recieve notification of the mouse clicks, but it won't respond to key events...
- Better still, add a "Start" button as well...

Comment: +1, I like the "Start" button as well. This is a better UI as the User will know what happens when enter is pressed or the button is clicked.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, be nice and mention why so we can learn and possibly update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    public class LeftPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {


    public LeftPanel(Tetris tetris) {
        this.tetris = tetris;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 480));
        setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(17f, 0.87f, 0.52f));
        JButton ExitGame = new JButton("Exit Game");
        ExitGame.addActionListener(this);
        ExitGame.setActionCommand("Exit");
        add(ExitGame );

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if("Exit".equals(e.getActionCommand())
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: While it makes the code cleaner (and probably work), it does not solve the problem of the button consuming the enter key, which the OP wants to use to start there game

Answer (score 0):

This line looks like a syntax error:

```
add(new JButton("Exit Game"));
    {
        ExitGame.addActionListener(this);
    }
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
ExitGame= new JButton("Exit");
this.add(ExitGame);
ExitGame.addActionListener(this);
```

I haven't tested this, but I think with some tweaking you should be able to get it to do what you want it to. I hope that works!

-Frank

Comment: While it makes the code cleaner (and probably work), it does not solve the problem of the button consuming the enter key, which the OP wants to use to start there game

Comment: Ah good point. Looking at your answer, maybe the OP could make the exit button have some sort of toggle on it since it's the only element that can be focused on. So initially it'd be a start button and then after pressing enter changing the button's functionality to the exit code. I guess you'd have to set some sort of boolean variable to check that against. Just one way to go about it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if("Exit".equals(e.getActionCommand())
```

System.exit(0);
    }

Comment: Can you at least give an explanation to your answer?

Answer (score -1):

As ActionlListener can be triggered by both Mouse and Keyboard, but now user only want to response mouse event, so change the action listener to mouselistener. Tested and passed.

```
public class LeftPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton ExitGame;

    public LeftPanel(Tetris tetris) {
        this.tetris = tetris;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 480));
        setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(17f, 0.87f, 0.52f));
        ExitGame= new JButton("Exit Game")
        add(ExitGame);
        ExitGame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               System.exit(0);  
           } 
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: This won't stop the `JButton` from responding to the enter key nor is it generally a good idea.  `JButton` uses the `ActionListener` for both mouse and key events

Comment: -1 A JButton was designed to be used with an ActionListener, not a MouseListener.

Comment: I don't know who said a JButton was designed to be used with an ActionListener; and I also wish you have tested my code before you added your comments.